# Can I set image as a title to UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to set some image as title of Navigation bar?

I think NYTimes application used a Navigation bar and title is look like image file (the reason why it's seems `UINavigationBar` is because they use right button to search).

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You can use an `UIImageView` for the `UINavigationItem.titleView` property, something like:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = myImageView;
```

Comment: Not necessarily relevant to the question, but if you want to alternate between the default title and an image title, you can go back to the default one by setting `self.navigationItem.titleView` to `nil`

Comment: This no longer works in iOS6. The image will be stretch and malformed.

Comment: in IOS6 you can now set an background image for the navigation bar.  However, if you are using this code and see the image stretched, you are not properly setting contentMode on the UIImageView you putting in the titleView.

Comment: @AuthmanApatira you are right, may you post a solution for iOS6.

Comment: for iOS6 add [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

Comment: what is the size of UIImage should be for title ?? i tried with 180*40 but it is getting blur.

Comment: Take a screen shot and measure the size of the image in the bar to see what the size is that you should use... usually blur is an indication that the image is not the same size.

Answer (score 16):

I find that a transparent .png at about 35px in height has worked well.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

//put logo image in the navigationBar

UIImageView* img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];
self.navigationItem.titleView = img;
[img release];

}
```

Comment: FYI: I think that line needs a release.

Comment: what is the size of UIImage should be for title ?? i tried with 180*40 but it is getting blur.

Answer (score 13):

You can do it right from storyboard (as of Xcode 7):

1. Create a view outside main view of view controller. It can be a nested view or just an image
2. Add navigation item to your view controller
3. Ctrl+ drag from navigation item and drop on outside view

[image]

4.select title view

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I have created a custom category for UINavigationBar as follows

**UINavigationBar+CustomImage.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UINavigationBar (CustomImage)
    - (void) setBackgroundImage:(UIImage*)image;
    - (void) clearBackgroundImage;
    - (void) removeIfImage:(id)sender;
@end
```

**UINavigationBar+CustomImage.m**

```
#import "UINavigationBar+CustomImage.h"

@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)

- (void) setBackgroundImage:(UIImage*)image {
    if (image == NULL) return;
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(110,5,100,30);
    [self addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];
}

- (void) clearBackgroundImage {
    NSArray *subviews = [self subviews];
    for (int i=0; i<[subviews count]; i++) {
        if ([[subviews objectAtIndex:i]  isMemberOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        [[subviews objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
    }
   }    
}

@end
```

I invoke it from my UINavigationController

```
[[navController navigationBar] performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setBackgroundImage:) withObject:image];
```

Answer (score 7):

This line will work for you, I always use this

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageNavBar.png"]  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 5):

I modified the UINavigationBar+CustomImage.m to have the title still visible to the user. Just use insertSubview: atIndex: instead of addSubview:

**UINavigationBar+CustomImage.m**

```
#import "UINavigationBar+CustomImage.h"

@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)

- (void) setBackgroundImage:(UIImage*)image {
    if (image == NULL) return;
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
    [self insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];
    [imageView release];
}

- (void) clearBackgroundImage {
    NSArray *subviews = [self subviews];
    for (int i=0; i<[subviews count]; i++) {
        if ([[subviews objectAtIndex:i]  isMemberOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        [[subviews objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
    }
   }    
}

@end
```

Comment: Hello. Title remained visible only on the immediate view, if the user navigates to other view ( using navigationController pushViewController), only the background appears. How can I address that?

Answer (score 5):

This also works well too

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setTitleView:[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourLogo"]]];
```

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me with UINavigationViewController - Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Do it quickly using storyboard and `@IBDesignable`:

```
@IBDesignable class AttributedNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    @IBInspectable var imageTitle: UIImage? = nil {

        didSet {

            guard let imageTitle = imageTitle else {

                topItem?.titleView = nil

                return
            }

            let imageView = UIImageView(image: imageTitle)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 30)
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

            topItem?.titleView = imageView
        }
    }
}
```

Then in attributes inspector just select an image:

[image]

and wait a second for result:

[image]

So setting view is there where it should be... in storyboard.

Answer (score 2):

For those who have the same error but in `Xamarin Forms`, the solution is to create a `Renderer` in `iOS` app and set the image like so :

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Page), typeof(MyApp.Renderers.NavigationPageRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Renderers
{
    #region using

    using UIKit;
    using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

    #endregion

    public class NavigationPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            SetTitleImage();
        }

        private void SetTitleImage()
        {
            UIImage logoImage = UIImage.FromFile(ResourceFiles.ImageResources.LogoImageName);
            UIImageView logoImageView = new UIImageView(logoImage);

            if (this.NavigationController != null)
            {
                this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.TopItem.TitleView = logoImageView;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
[navController.navigationBar insertSubview:myImage atIndex:0] ;
```

where myImage is of type UIImageView
and navController is of type UINavigationController

Answer (score 0):

I modified the UINavigationBar+CustomImage code to properly work without leaking memory.

```
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    if (! image) return;
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
    [self addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];
}

- (void) clearBackgroundImage
{
    // This runs on a separate thread, so give it it's own pool
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSArray *mySubviews = self.subviews;

    // Move in reverse direction as not to upset the order of elements in the array
    for (int i = [mySubviews count] - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if ([[mySubviews objectAtIndex:i] isMemberOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
        {
            [[mySubviews objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    [pool release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is how you would do this in (Xamarin's) MonoTouch with C#.NET

Create a UIViewConvrtoller that is in a NavigationController then call this at any time:

```
someNiceViewControllerYouMade.NavigationController.NavigationBar
     .InsertSubview(new UIImageView
     (MediaProvider.GetImage(ImageGeneral.navBar_667x44)),0);
```

Note: MediaProvider is just a class that fetches images.

This example allows for the view to fill the full Navigation Bar , and lets the text for the items caption appear too.

Answer (score 0):

If your buttons disappear when you navigate back and forth the navigation, this fixed it for me:

```
NSArray *mySubviews = navigationBar.subviews;
UIImageView *iv = nil;

// Move in reverse direction as not to upset the order of elements in the array
for (int i = [mySubviews count] - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if ([[mySubviews objectAtIndex:i] isMemberOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"found background at index %d",i);
        iv = [mySubviews objectAtIndex:i];
        [[mySubviews objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
        [navigationBar insertSubview:iv atIndex:0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ios5.0 introduced a heap of features to customise the appearance of standard elements. If you didn't want to use an ImageView for the title, an alternative would be to customise the appearance of all UINavbars using a background image and a custom font/colour.

```
- (void) customiseMyNav
{
    // Create resizable images
    UIImage *portraitImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bar_bg_portrait"] 
        resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    UIImage *landscapeImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bar_bg_landscape"] 
        resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

    // Set the background image
    [[UINavigationBar appearance]  setBackgroundImage:portraitImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance]  setBackgroundImage:landscapeImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];

    // set the title appearance
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            [UIColor colorWithRed:50.0/255.0 green:150.0/255.0 blue:100/255.0 alpha:1.0], 
            UITextAttributeTextColor, 
            [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.6], 
            UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, 
            [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)], 
            UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, 
            [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-Bold" size:0.0], 
            UITextAttributeFont, 
            nil]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In MonoTouch you can use this:

```
 this.NavigationItem.TitleView = myImageView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add image to naviagtionBar with **SWIFT** that scales to fit and clips to bounds. You can call this function inside the view controllers viewDidLoad() function.

```
func setupNavigationBarWithTitleImage(titleImage: UIImage) {

    let imageView = UIImageView(image: titleImage)
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    navigationItem.titleView = imageView

}
```