# Use Background Image to UINavigationController among multiple views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

How can I use a background image for UINavigationController, while maintaining the title? The answer from [ck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289441/uinavigationcontroller-title-can-be-some-image/428434#428434) on other thread did the trick to put the image and keep the text. But if the user navigates to other view ( using [navigationController pushViewController]), only the background appears in the new screen.

How can one change the background image for UINavigationController, while maintaining the title across multiple views?

Comment: I'm sure I added the link. Don't know what happened. Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289441/uinavigationcontroller-title-can-be-some-image/428434#428434

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create a CustomUIViewController that extends UIViewController and override viewDidLoad to something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];
}
```

After that, use your CustomUIViewController in your controllers.

Answer (score 5):

And if you want to use ImageView to scale it :

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:controller.view.bounds];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"aluminium-brushed-metal-background-texture-hd-575x400.jpg"];
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
[navigationController.view insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];
```