# Set NavigationBar background to a solid color

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

Is there any way I can set the background of the Navigation Bar of the `UINavigationController` to a solid color?

I know I can change the Tint color, but that still leaves me with the gradient/glass effect.

Any way I can get rid of that, and just have a plain old solid color?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to subclass UINavigationBar and override `-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect`:

```
UIColor *colorFlat = /* any UIColor*/
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [colorFlat CGColor]);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
```

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm. To set the colors of the buttons, I changed the tint color of the Navigation Bar, and they get the tint color. Just as I expected.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to do via the appearance proxy? `[[UINavigationBar appearance] .....];`

Comment: I don't know, I use this code in a project with iOS 4.2 when appearance wasn't available

Comment: Overriding drawRect causes problems on iOS7; it becomes 44 px and leaves an empty statusBar

Answer (score 47):

The following code also results in solid color of navigation bar:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: Be sure to also set the tint color or your buttons on the nav bar will not get the color: [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

Comment: Where do you do this? I'm trying to do it in the viewDidLoad of the view controller with the navigation bar and it does not seem to take effect. Does it need to be done sometime earlier. I have a storyboard which appears to be overriding it.

Comment: David, it has to be done before you present the view. Configuring "appearance" doesn't update visible views. If you want to set this globally the best place to do it would be in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:.

Answer (score 0):

I used to override drawRect method and fill color; but after iOS7 upgrade it causes some problems on UINavigationBar. If you write your own drawrect method, even if you call [super drawRect], it changes the bar's dimension and you end up with a navigationBar with 44 pixels height. The status bar is left empty.

To get a solid colored navigationBar, I used an image as background image (any small solid colored image will do since you are stretching it) and added this lines inside the initWithFrame method of the UINavigationBar subclass:

```
[self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]     
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgimage.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
```

Answer (score -4):

Create a **CustomUIViewController** that extends **UIViewController** and override **viewDidLoad** to something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.0 green: 0.0 blue: 1.0 alpha: 1.0];
}
```

After that, use your CustomUIViewController in your controllers.

[Credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5785385/882217)

Comment: Isn't possible to do without an image?

Comment: Shure, sorry for the mistake, try using: [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.0 green: 0.0 blue: 1.0 alpha: 1.0]

Comment: No luck. Shouldn't I set the background on the navigationbar? e.g. `self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor`? Which doesn't work either :)

Comment: question is how to set navbar bg color, not uiviewcontroller bg color